# Choosing appropriate capacitor value from ripple

Tags: pwm, capacitance, ripple

I have a H-bridge driving a 12V motor that at 100% duty cycle draws around 15A. To start the motor I am applying a soft-start, the duty cycle of PWM to H-bridge goes from around 60% to 100% and PWM frequency is around 500Hz.

How can I calculate the needed capacitor value on 12V for 10% ripple? At such high currents and low PWM frequency would it be better to go for more than 10% ripple (this 12V line isnt driving anything else than motor)?

I am aware of: $$I=C\times\frac{dV}{dt}$$
But plugging the numbers in I get: $$C=\frac{I\times dt}{dV}=\frac{15*\frac{1}{500}}{1.2}=25mF$$

Which seems quite high to me, is this correct?

Comment: The calculation you did does not include the current delivered by the power supply.     You need to specify what the 12 V power supply is (current, ripple), and what drop in the 12 V supply do you see currently on starting?

Comment: @JackCreasey Its night here, so I will do this tommorow. But so you dont wait, what would be the calculation then?

Comment: Essentially the same, though this time you will actually know what the ripple value is. I doubt your power supply is dropping by 10% (1.2 V), and if it is, then you probably need to be working on it first. I'd expect that you might expect droop values of around only 1% maximum from your power supply.

Comment: May I ask why would you reduce voltage ripple out of your H-bridge? And exact schematic you are planning for?

Comment: @carloc I said I would increase voltage ripple, so that smaller capacitor could be used. Its just a normal H-bridge with PMOS on top and NMOS on bottom. NMOS gets driven by PWM.

Comment: Oh yes okay, but this does not answer my doubts. So where are you going to wire the capacitor? Across supply feeding the bridge I guess? And why are you so concerned with ripple over there?

Comment: @carloc Yes. Well, I am guessing drawing 15A in periods would cause serious voltage sag.

Comment: Okay . I believe you over estimate capacitor. I'd rather try to analyze an RLC circuit including power supply and cabling stray L and R and capacitors with their ESR. A few runs on a simulator with different  duty cycle are going to be the fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For similar problems, with 10% V ripple , I let RC= 8T.
If motor equiv R=12V/15A and T= 1/500Hz=2ms then **C=8*2ms*15A/12V= 20 mF**

(assuming your current is RMS)

This is consistent with your calculation and you can achieve this with a power supply with Zout = <<10% of load or better with a 12V battery and trickle charger.  Batteries have much larger capacitance and low ESR and would perform better but Caps will be [cheaper](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cornell-dubilier-electronics-cde/SLPX223M016E3P3/338-3808-ND/1882273).

However since startup current due to DCR of motor can be up to 10x Imax rated current, soft start is necessary or a much higher capacity such as from a battery.